# Where is the PowerPC version of 11.04?

Tags: 11.04, downloads, ppc, cd-image

Anyone know where the powerpc iso for natty is?  I found the one for oneiric -- http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/daily/current/ but there is not one for natty in http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/ports/releases/

Comment: What computer do you have that can use 11.04?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is [no **official** PowerPC support in Ubuntu since 7.04](https://lists.ubuntu.com/archives/ubuntu-announce/2007-February/000098.html).

Unofficial ports are made exclusively by volunteers, and always lag a bit behind. So I guess you just have to be patient.

Comment: ok, thanks.  I was aware that the powerpc port was not supported, but I was just a little curious as to why oneiric had a powerpc and natty did not.  Thanks for the info!

Comment: My guess is that daily build is by no means guaranteed to work properly, while the other URL is for **released** versions (meaning that someone tested them and considered stable enough for release). There is no daily build for Natty, because the daily builds are created only for the version currently in development.

Answer (score 1):

official version of the PowerPC desktop CD Natty had a tremendous Ubiquity bug in the installer had no possible to create a repository configuration to update and complete the installation and pre-installed base in the previous steps of the installer, so in many cases not even ended up creating a user account with which to start a session, leaving practically for expert users to correct these bugs in ubuntu with console to access the desktop of Ubuntu 11.04, but if you want this CD version of "natty-desktop- powerpc.iso "you search the web if any mirror somewhere in the world still has it for reasons of history for cases like yours, in this case I found the version natty in Kubuntu (KDE desktop) in the mirror of the university Harvard (23-June-2011): http://mirrors.med.harvard.edu/ubuntu-cdimage/kubuntu/daily-live/current/, I hope that this version does not have the same problem as the natty Ubuntu version ( gnome desktop), and I think that the installer problem was the reason to withdraw the PowerPC line Ubuntu 11.04

Answer (score 1):

I found a CD ISO in this link for Oneiric 11.10 on powerpc, I am downloading it now, so...

Well, this is the link:
http://mirrors.med.harvard.edu/ubuntu-cdimage/daily/20110926/

Comment: Mirror server is dead.